# OpenOffice Writer - Apply same style

Tags: openoffice

I have a chunk of text that has style "JBody" (custom). However JBody is defined with Times New Roman, and the text is using Arial. When I select the text and click JBody (again) -- nothing happens.

How can I tell OO to ignore overrides and just use the actual definition of the style?
How can I apply this to the entire document to make sure no text is outside of the style that it's told to be?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be glad if someone could migrate it. I saw other questions about OO on unix.stackexchange. Overall not sure where it fits best

Comment: Lets see if anyone shares my opinion, of course ppl are free to reply to this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're searching the `Default Formatting` functionality. It's the first entry in the `Format` menu.

Just select the complete content (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to restore default style-defined formats.

Comment: Was not aware of this, and never saw it while looking! Life saver :)